# Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I got an error -

> Column 'Employee.EmpID' is invalid in the select list because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

---

```
select loc.LocationID, emp.EmpID
from Employee as emp full join Location as loc 
on emp.LocationID = loc.LocationID
group by loc.LocationID
```

This situation fits into the answer given by Bill Karwin.

correction for above, fits into answer by ExactaBox -

```
select loc.LocationID, count(emp.EmpID) -- not count(*), don't want to count nulls
from Employee as emp full join Location as loc 
on emp.LocationID = loc.LocationID
group by loc.LocationID
```

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION -**

For the SQL query -

```
select *
from Employee as emp full join Location as loc 
on emp.LocationID = loc.LocationID
group by (loc.LocationID)
```

I don't understand why I get this error. All I want to do is join the tables and then group all the employees in a particular location together.

**I think I have a partial explanation for my own question. Tell me if its ok -**

To group all employees that work in the same location we have to first mention the LocationID.

Then, we cannot/do not mention each employee ID next to it. Rather, we mention the total number of employees in that location, ie we should SUM() the employees working in that location. Why do we do it the latter way, i am not sure. 
So, this explains the "it is not contained in either an aggregate function" part of the error.

What is the explanation for the **`GROUP BY`** clause part of the error ?

Comment: When you use group by you have to select the thing specifically that you are grouping

Comment: You are probably confusing `GROUP BY` with `ORDER BY`.  Grouping is used to aggregate columns; ordering is sorting the result.

Answer (score 722, accepted):

Suppose I have the following table `T`:

```
a   b
--------
1   abc
1   def
1   ghi
2   jkl
2   mno
2   pqr
```

And I do the following query:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM T
GROUP BY a
```

The output should have two rows, one row where `a=1` and a second row where `a=2`.

But what should the value of *b* show on each of these two rows? There are three possibilities in each case, and nothing in the query makes it clear which value to choose for b in each group. It's ambiguous.

This demonstrates the *single-value rule*, which prohibits the undefined results you get when you run a GROUP BY query, and you include any columns in the select-list that are neither part of the grouping criteria, nor appear in aggregate functions (SUM, MIN, MAX, etc.).

Fixing it might look like this:

```
SELECT a, MAX(b) AS x
FROM T
GROUP BY a
```

Now it's clear that you want the following result:

```
a   x
--------
1   ghi
2   pqr
```

Comment: Bill - an aside - you said that its not "clear which value to choose for b in each group". Why doesn't SQL put b1,b2,b3 all together in that column ?

Comment: @davidblaine, MySQL has a function GROUP_CONCAT() for that.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat But in standard SQL, each column should contain only one value.  That's fundamental to relational theory too.

Comment: Love it when folks take the time to explain using first principles.  Excellent explanation Bill.  Thanks.

Comment: I think this is negative point of MSSQL because when we have some LEFT JOINs and group by the PK of the right table then reasonably we must be able to get the columns of the right table easily without ANY AMBIGUOUS situation (MySQL handles this).

Comment: Also AFAIK MsSQL had some trick like GROUP_CONCAT too... hmm... something like STUFF(( SELECT (' - '+ColName) AS ColName .... FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 3, '').

Comment: In SQL Server 2017 you can use String_Agg to solve the above problem

Comment: @Postlagerkarte, that's good to hear that they finally made an aggregate function to do this common task. It always seemed like an ugly hack to use FOR XML PATH.

Comment: Every couple of years when I need to know this stuff, I find myself coming back to this exact answer. This explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 98):

Your query will work in `MYSQL` if you set to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` server mode (*and by default It is*). But in this case, you are using different RDBMS. So to make your query work, **add all non-aggregated columns** to your `GROUP BY` clause, eg

```
SELECT col1, col2, SUM(col3) totalSUM
FROM tableName
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Non-Aggregated columns means the column is not pass into aggregated functions like `SUM`, `MAX`, `COUNT`, etc..

Comment: this works like a charm with multiple inner joins.

Comment: how can I write with ef core

Answer (score 21):

> "All I want to do is join the tables and then group all the employees
>   in a particular location together."

It sounds like what you want is for the output of the SQL statement to list every employee in the company, but first all the people in the Anaheim office, then the people in the Buffalo office, then the people in the Cleveland office (A, B, C, get it, obviously I don't know what locations you have).

In that case, lose the GROUP BY statement.  All you need is  `ORDER BY loc.LocationID`

Comment: Thats not what i meant. order by will put all employees in the same city one after the other. It will do this for all the cities. I needed to know *how many* employees in a city instead of *which employees* in a city. makes sense ?

Comment: then replace the first line of your original example with: SELECT loc.LocationID, COUNT(*)

Comment: yeah, thats what i wanted. Thanks. Looks like i did not frame my question properly. But, Bill Karwin's answer made me understand the reason behind the error. So I accepted his. Thanks again.

Answer (score 19):

Basically, what this error is saying is that if you are going to use the `GROUP BY` clause, then your result is going to be a relation/table with a row for each group, so in your `SELECT` statement you can only "select" the column that you are grouping by and use aggregate functions on that column because the other columns will not appear in the resulting table.

Comment: Good summary. I have posted a complementary answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63545571/2806819