# select query in subquery giving Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following query which i want to get sum counts for my data

```
SELECT  
  TI.[text] as zone,
  YEAR (ER.Inserted) as [Year], 
  SUM(CONVERT(INT,DRT.RDRT)) as RDRT,
  SUM(CONVERT(INT,DRT.FACT)) as FACT ,
  SUM(CONVERT(INT,DRT.ERU))  as ERU,
  (
     SELECT COUNT(ER1.ReportID) 
     FROM dbo.EW_Reports ER1
     INNER JOIN  dbo.EW_Report_InformationManagement ERI ON ER1.ReportID = ERI.ReportID
     INNER JOIN EW_Report_Country ERC1 ON   ER1.ReportID = ERC1.ReportID 
     INNER JOIN ApplicationDB.dbo.Country C1 ON ERC1.CountryID = C1.countryId 
     INNER JOIN ApplicationDB.dbo.Region R1 ON C1.regionId = R1.regionId
     INNER JOIN ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone Z1  ON R1.zoneId = Z1.zoneId 
     WHERE ERI.EmergencyAppeal IS NOT NULL
      AND (YEAR ( ER1.Inserted) = YEAR ( ER.Inserted))
      AND Z1.zoneId =  Z.zoneId     
   ) as emergencyAppeals    
FROM     EW_Reports ER 
INNER JOIN EW_DisasterResponseTools DRT ON   ER.ReportID = DRT.ReportID 
INNER JOIN EW_Report_Country ERC ON   ER.ReportID = ERC.ReportID  
INNER JOIN ApplicationDB.dbo.Country C ON ERC.CountryID = c.countryId 
INNER JOIN ApplicationDB.dbo.Region R ON c.regionId = R.regionId
INNER JOIN ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone Z ON R.zoneId = Z.zoneId 
INNER JOIN ApplicationDB.dbo.Translation T ON Z.translationId = T.translationId
INNER JOIN ApplicationDB.dbo.TranslationItem TI ON T.translationId = TI.translationId
INNER JOIN EW_lofDisasterTypes D ON ER.DisasterTypeID = D.TranslationID AND D.LanguageID = 1 AND TI.languageID = 1      
WHERE (YEAR ( ER.Inserted) IN (2011,2012))
GROUP BY TI.[text], YEAR (ER.Inserted)
```

But its giving following error

> Column 'ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone.zoneId' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Please assist me how to resolve this error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are too many ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone.zoneId records in your table already

simple add ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone.zoneId in group by then problem will solved

```
Select ....
.....
GROUP BY TI.[text], YEAR (ER.Inserted) ,ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone.zoneId
```

For your question  why u need to add ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone.zoneId in my group as i am using that in ur subquery, this is because u perform a outer condition in your subquery

```
SELECT
----
(
SELECT
-----
INNER JOIN ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone Z1  ON R1.zoneId = Z1.zoneId 
WHERE
----
AND Z1.zoneId =  Z.zoneId 
)
-----
INNER JOIN ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone Z ON R.zoneId = Z.zoneId
WHERE (YEAR ( ER.Inserted) IN (2011,2012)) 
------
```

note that you have a condition in  different years

so your data flow may like this

```
ZoneID    Years     Record
  1       2011        1000
  1       2012        1000
```

same zone id contain different years, without proper grouping, sql got no way to group years column

Comment: thanks its solved my problem but can you please tell me why i need to add ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone.zoneId in my group as i am using that in my subquery ?

Comment: answer updated, for better explanation, maybe u can take a look on this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e

Comment: No, this is not the answer, because adding  ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone.zoneId has physical result in grouping by this column. Yes, adding  ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone.zoneId remove error, but thw select result could by wrong.

Answer (score 0):

it is showing the error because you have used this in sub query where condition

you need toadd  ApplicationDB.dbo.Zone.zoneId in group by