# SQL assigning name to the SUM of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

SO i've been working on a series of sql commands / reports. I'm trying to get the SUM of total incidents that a particular individual creates then keeps adding to daily if incidents occur. So if Tim gets an incident 1 day, then 0 the next, then 2 the following day, it'll show his name next to 3 incidents.

Example:
TableA

```
Tim | 1 | day one
Tim | 0 | day two
Tim | 2 | day three
```

TableB

```
Tim | 3 | week1
```

Here are some SQL commands I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO WeeklyReport(ImportDate, DayofData, [Name], TotalA, TotalB, TotalC)
SELECT GETDATE() AS ImportDate, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DayofData, p.[Name], SUM(p.IncidentA), SUM(c.IncidentB), SUM(n.IncidentC)
FROM TableA p
INNER JOIN TableB c ON c.[Name] = p.[Name]
INNER JOIN TableC n ON n.[Name] = p.[Name]
```

I run into this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Column 'TableA.Name' is invalid in
>   the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

What changes can be made to the command to better accommodate this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty basic thing, You need to add the `non-aggregate` column's in `Group by` when a `Aggregate` function is used in `Select` list

```
INSERT INTO weeklyreport 
            (importdate, 
             dayofdata, 
             [name], 
             totala, 
             totalb, 
             totalc) 
SELECT Getdate()                   AS ImportDate, --Constant so allowed
       Dateadd(day, -1, Getdate()) AS DayofData, --Constant so allowed
       p.[name],  -- Non Aggregate column should be present in Group by
       Sum(p.incidenta), 
       Sum(c.incidentb), 
       Sum(n.incidentc) 
FROM   tablea p 
       INNER JOIN tableb c 
               ON c.[name] = p.[name] 
       INNER JOIN tablec n 
               ON n.[name] = p.[name] 
GROUP  BY P.[name]
```

Comment: this works, since my data is based on daily reports, if say day 1 incident is reported, next day same incident occurred, will it count both and just display "2"?

Comment: @Sam - Yes i think. Sample data and expected result will help us to understand better

Comment: sorry for delayed response thank you, I'm going to test this but for the most part this is answering my question. Thank you very much