# Sum Sql column with join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying this code:

```
Select  C.CustomerNum
      , C.Coupon
      , C.name
      , C.Surname
      , Sum(P.Points)
From    customers C
Join    Points P
        On P.CustomerNum = C.CustomerNum
Where   C.Coupon = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-x';
```

I'm getting error:

> Msg 8118, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'C.CustomerNum' is invalid
>   in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate
>   function and there is no GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What do you want SUM to base upon? The error is self-explanatory

Comment: For getting my total points in same row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Comment: add `GROUP BY c.CustomerNum, C.Coupon, C.Name, C.Surname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an aggregate (SUM, COUNT, AVERAGE) you need to group your query by all the non-aggregate columns returned.  For this:

```
Select  C.CustomerNum
      , C.Coupon
      , C.name
      , C.Surname
      , Sum(P.Points)
From    customers C
Join    Points P
        On P.CustomerNum = C.CustomerNum
Where   C.Coupon = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-x'; 
Group By C.CustomerNum
      , C.Coupon
      , C.name
      , C.Surname
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use.

```
SELECT C.CustomerNum,
       C.Coupon,
       C.name,
       C.Surname,
       P.Points
FROM   customers C
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Sum(Points) AS Points,
                                    CustomerNum
                   FROM   Points
                   GROUP  BY CustomerNum) P
         ON P.CustomerNum = C.CustomerNum
WHERE  C.Coupon = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-x';
```

To avoid having to add all the selected columns from `customers` to the `GROUP BY` list.

Answer (score 0):

The error message lays it out. You can do this (select only aggregates without a group by):

```
Select  Sum(P.Points)
From    customers C
Join    Points P
        On P.CustomerNum = C.CustomerNum
Where   C.Coupon = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-x';
```

or this (select aggregate and columns if columns are in group by):

```
Select  C.CustomerNum
      , Sum(P.Points)
From    customers C
Join    Points P
        On P.CustomerNum = C.CustomerNum
Where   C.Coupon = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-x'
group by c.customernum
```

but not this (select aggregates and columns without a group by):

```
Select  C.CustomerNum
      , C.Coupon
      , C.name
      , C.Surname
      , Sum(P.Points)
From    customers C
Join    Points P
        On P.CustomerNum = C.CustomerNum
Where   C.Coupon = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-x';
```

Comment: Doesnt work the second case neither i take same error message

Comment: I didn't add what your query should be. Just trying to help explain the error message. Check someone else's answer for a copy/paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

When using an Aggregate function, you need to use a `GROUP BY`. Try this:

```
Select  C.CustomerNum
      , C.Coupon
      , C.name
      , C.Surname
      , Sum(P.Points)
From    customers C
Join    Points P
        On P.CustomerNum = C.CustomerNum
Where   C.Coupon = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-x'; 
GROUP BY C.CustomerNum
      , C.Coupon
      , C.name
      , C.Surname
```

Now, you'll probably want to narrow down what you actually want to select. For instance, it might be best to just group by C.Surname or C.CustomerNum

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an aggregate function (in this case `SUM()`) with other non-aggregated columns without using a `GROUP BY`.  However, you can do it by making this a windowed `SUM()` function:

```
Select  C.CustomerNum
      , C.Coupon
      , C.name
      , C.Surname
      , Sum(P.Points) Over (Partition By C.CustomerNum)
From    customers C
Join    Points P
        On P.CustomerNum = C.CustomerNum
Where   C.Coupon = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-x';
```

But perhaps you're wanting to group them by the `CustomerNum`, `Coupon`, `Name`, and `Surname`, in which case, you just need to add a `GROUP BY`:

```
Select  C.CustomerNum
      , C.Coupon
      , C.name
      , C.Surname
      , Sum(P.Points)
From    customers C
Join    Points P
        On P.CustomerNum = C.CustomerNum
Where   C.Coupon = 'xxx-xxx-xxx-x'
Group By C.CustomerNum, C.Coupon, C.Name, C.Surname
```

Answer (score 0):

@User6927546

If you are using mysql than it should work because i have cross checked same and its working fine.

select employee.empId ,employee.Name ,sum(w.workcode) from employee 
join works w on employee.workId=w.id where employee.Name='anoop'

I get the result set as :
empId     Name      sum(w.workcode)
1         Anoop     200