# Group By: What if I don't want to perform an aggregate function on a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table, Students, with the following columns:

```
________________________________________________
| id   |  name  |  class  |  date_registrered  | 
------------------------------------------------
```

I want to select one row for every unique class, and only the row with the largest value in date_registrered,
i.e. I want to select the latest registrered Student for every class, including all the data for that one.

I tried:

```
SELECT id, name, class, MAX(date_registrered)
FROM Students
GROUP BY class;
```

I get the following error:

> Column 'Students.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e) adresses a simplified version of this issue. However, the example is for 2 columns only.

I only want to group by class, and I only want to perform an aggregate function on date_registrered. I also want to display all the other columns for the row with the max date_registrered for every class.

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: If two students register on the same day, *latest registered student for every class* has no well-defined meaning. At least not in the context of returning one row per unique class.

Comment: The time is in milliseconds, so its fine

Comment: In that case, "date_registered" deserves a more thoughtful name.

Comment: My english is pretty bad, but I get your point:)

Comment: No, your English is *excellent*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT id, name, class, date_registrered
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by class ORDER BY date_registrered DESC) rn
       FROM Students
     ) T
WHERE T.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message explains your issue very well, you can't perform an aggregation on one column, and not use the rest in the `GROUP BY`. In this case, you'll want to use something like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  id,
            name,
            class,
            date_registered,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY class ORDER BY date_registrered DESC)
    FROM students
)
SELECT  id,
        name,
        class,
        date_registered
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```