# SQL Server 2014 - How to group by date only from a datetime column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, grouping

I have a table that lists data every 15 minutes. So my date column data is like '2017-04-18 00:15:00.000'

I'm trying to get sum of those columns for that entire day but my grouping doesn't want to work.

```
SELECT 
    Sum(Field 1),
    Sum(Field 2),
    Sum(Field 3)
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE 
    StartDate >= '2017-04-18'
    AND StartDate <= '2017-04-19'
GROUP BY 
    CAST(StartDate AS DATE)
    --GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10),StartDate,103)
    --GROUP BY StartDate
```

The `GROUP BY StartDate` gives me records like so:

```
2017-04-18 08:00:00.000 13  3   22  0
2017-04-18 08:15:00.000 15  1   16  0
2017-04-18 08:30:00.000 14  7   13  0
2017-04-18 08:45:00.000 16  3   18  0
2017-04-18 09:00:00.000 17  4   21  0
```

I've tried:

```
GROUP BY CAST(StartDate AS DATE)
```

as well as

```
GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(10), StartDate, 103)
```

These above two group by clauses give me the same error message:

> The column 'StartDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How would I `GROUP` by Date so that I can `GROUP` the data by date as '2017-04-18'

Comment: Don't put `startdate` in your SELECT. Instead put `CAST(STartdate as Date) as startDate` in your select so it matches your group by.

Comment: @jevill Not required in select i think

Comment: Thank you JNevill and @KannanKandasamy. That worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Answer (score 1):

You can try a query like below

```
SELECT 
      CAST(StartDate AS DATE) as S
      ,Sum(Field 1)
      ,Sum(Field 2)
      ,Sum(Field 3)

FROM MyTable

WHERE StartDate >= '2017-04-18'
  AND StartDate <= '2017-04-19'

GROUP BY CAST(StartDate AS DATE)
```