# How to Group By a column - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, group-by, sql-server-2016

I need to group by an `UniqueIdentifier` column, the table also contains the XML column.

Table schema: **StudentMark**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentMark]
(
    [StudentMarkId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [SubjectId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ScoreInfo] [xml] NULL,
    [GeneratedOn] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentMark] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentMarkId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample seed data

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StudentMark] ([StudentId], [SubjectId], [ScoreInfo], GeneratedOn])
VALUES ('FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581', '0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-10 10:20:15'),
       ('0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2', '0D72F79E-FB48-4D3E-9906-B78A9D105081', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-10 10:20:15'),
       ('0F4EF48C-93E3-41AA-8295-F6B0E8D8C3A2', 'AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-16 09:06:20'),
       ('FC3CB475-B480-4129-9190-6DE880E2D581', 'AB172272-D2E9-49E1-8040-6117BB6743DB', '<StudentMarkAttribute xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></StudentMarkAttribute>', '2017-08-16 09:06:20');
```

**Requirement**: I need to group by `[dbo].[StudentMark].[StudentId]` and take the latest record.

I tried the following SQL query but it is causing an error

```
SELECT 
    MAX([StudentMarkId]), [StudentId], [SubjectId], [ScoreInfo], [GeneratedOn]
FROM 
    [dbo].[StudentMark] 
GROUP BY 
    [StudentId]
```

**Error**:

> Column 'dbo.StudentMark.SubjectId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I refereed the following question but I can't fix it: [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to calculate position within group:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StudentId ORDER BY StudentMarkId DESC) AS rn
    FROM [dbo].[StudentMark]) sub
WHERE sub.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Could you please confirm, we can't use the `Group By` ? instead of `Row_Number` approach ?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan You can't use GROUP BY in the manner that you've proposed. Your problem is clear `greatest nth per group`

Comment: Could you please confirm which answer is preferable ? In terms of Optimization out of two answers ?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan I would strongly suggest to do testing by yourself and compare. I don't know your env, settings and so on.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution works best if you have a `Students` table:

```
select sm.*
from students s cross apply
     (select top 1 sm.*
      from studentmark sm
      where sm.studentid = s.studentid
      order by sm.generatedon desc
     ) sm;
```

Comment: Could you please confirm, which one is preferable you approach or `Row_Number` approach ? which one is efficient ?

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan . . . You should try on your data to see which performs better.  With an index on `studentmark(studentid, generatedon)`, I would expect this to be slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot group by `XML` or `TEXT` columns, you would first need to convert to `varchar(max)`:

```
SELECT 
    MAX([StudentMarkId]), [StudentId], [SubjectId],
    CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [ScoreInfo])) DetailXML,
    [GeneratedOn]
FROM 
    [dbo].[StudentMark] 
GROUP BY 
    [StudentId], [SubjectId], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [ScoreInfo]), [GeneratedOn]
```

On the first line, it is converted to varchar(max) to match the GROUP BY clause, and later it is re-cast back to XML.

Comment: Its returning all four records.