# sql query error-invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT  i.DocumentNo,i.DocumentDate,i.Qty, pa.ProductCode,
        MAX(pmx.ProductName),pa.ProductAssembleCode, 
        MAX(pm.ProductName) ProductAsemblyName,
        MAX(pa.ProductAssembleUnit),pa.ProductAssembleQty,
        MAX(pa.ProductAssembleUnitCost), pa.ProductAssembleCostValue
FROM    dbo.InvSales i
INNER JOIN dbo.InvProductAssemble pa ON i.ProductCode = pa.ProductCode
INNER JOIN dbo.InvProductMaster pm ON pa.ProductAssembleID = pm.InvProductMasterID
INNER JOIN dbo.InvProductMaster pmx ON i.ProductID = pmx.InvProductMasterID
WHERE DocumentDate BETWEEN '2016-06-10' AND '2017-12-14'
GROUP BY i.ProductCode,ProductAssembleCode
```

this is my Query for food coasting report .i cant find what is the error of this query
error- Column 'dbo.InvSales.DocumentNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message tells you what the problem is:

```
SELECT
      i.DocumentNo -- dbo.InvSales.DocumentNo' is invalid in the select list
    , i.DocumentDate
    , i.Qty
    , pa.ProductCode
    , MAX(pmx.ProductName)
    , pa.ProductAssembleCode
    , MAX(pm.ProductName) productasemblyname
    , MAX(pa.ProductAssembleUnit)
    , pa.ProductAssembleQty
    , MAX(pa.ProductAssembleUnitCost)
    , pa.ProductAssembleCostValue
FROM dbo.InvSales i
INNER JOIN dbo.InvProductAssemble pa ON i.ProductCode = pa.ProductCode
INNER JOIN dbo.InvProductMaster pm ON pa.ProductAssembleID = pm.InvProductMasterID
INNER JOIN dbo.InvProductMaster pmx ON i.ProductID = pmx.InvProductMasterID
WHERE DocumentDate BETWEEN '2016-06-10' AND '2017-12-14'
GROUP BY
      i.DocumentNo -- because is WAS NOT HERE as well
    , i.DocumentDate
    , i.Qty
    , pa.ProductCode
    , pa.ProductAssembleCode
    , pa.ProductAssembleQty
    , pa.ProductAssembleCostValue
```

Any column in the select list, that is NOT using an aggregate function, should be listed in the `group by` clause. If you don't do that the error message will occur and it is trying to say:

1. put the column into the `group by` clause, OR
2. you may have forgotten to use an aggregate function on that column

It's most commonly problem 1