# Why am I getting "column invalid" error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have converted mysql query to a SQL Server T-SQL query, and when I run this query, I get an error:

> Column invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Here is my query, can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error ?

```
SELECT 
    t.id, t.value, t.branch_id, k.name 
FROM  
    tb_target as t 
LEFT JOIN 
    tb_keyindicator as k ON k.id = t.keyindicator_id 
WHERE 
    t.branch_id IN (241) 
    AND t.period >= '2017-09' 
    AND t.period < '2017-10' 
GROUP BY 
    branch_id;
```

Comment: Because of the exact reason the error says... You can't use GROUP BY unless all the columns in the SELECT list are a) also in GROUP BY or b) are used with an aggregate function. Think about this logically, how could you have a list of items and a summary on the same line in the same column?

Comment: @JacobH Or if the other columns are functionally determined by one of the group by columns, e.g. a primary key

Comment: Can you please help me how can i resolve this error ?  How this query can be run ?

Comment: @NikulPanchal Why do you think you even need `GROUP BY` here?

Comment: Ask a new question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'm with @TimBiegeleisen. What are you trying to accomplish here? I'm guessing a window function is what you really want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen,to remove duplicate record

Comment: Thanks to all of you, i have resolved the issue now

Answer (score 1):

You have to include all the columns in the select that are not aggregated in the group by clause. So your query should be:

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, t.branch_id, k.name 
FROM tb_target as t 
LEFT JOIN tb_keyindicator as k ON k.id = t.keyindicator_id 
WHERE t.branch_id IN (241) AND t.period >= '2017-09' AND t.period <  '2017-10' 
GROUP BY t.id, t.value, t.branch_id, k.name;
```

Comment: Of course, if you're going to group by on all columns in the select list and not use any aggregates at all, it's clearer to switch to `DISTINCT` and remove the group by clause entirely.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is synthaxically simpler than using `DISTINCT` in this case.

Comment: @cdaiga - from a `SELECT` without a `GROUP BY` nor a `DISTINCT`. To get distinct values, you can a) add the word `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` clause or b) add a `GROUP BY` clause that lists all columns from the `SELECT` clause again. How is (b) simpler?

Answer (score 0):

If grouping is correct, you have to apply [aggregate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql) to following fields: `t.id, t.value, k.name`.  See more discussion about similar error on another SO topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e).

Example:

```
SELECT MIN(t.id), MIN(t.value), t.branch_id, MIN(k.name)
FROM tb_target as t 
LEFT JOIN tb_keyindicator as k ON k.id = t.keyindicator_id 
WHERE t.branch_id IN (241) AND t.period >= '2017-09' AND t.period < '2017-10' 
GROUP BY branch_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, t.branch_id, k.name 
FROM tb_target as t 
LEFT JOIN tb_keyindicator as k ON k.id = t.keyindicator_id 
WHERE t.branch_id IN (241) AND t.period >= '2017-09' AND t.period < '2017-10' 
GROUP BY branch_id;
```

As your query is written, you dont need the

```
group by
```

part.
 So your query should be like this.

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, t.branch_id, k.name 
FROM tb_target as t 
LEFT JOIN tb_keyindicator as k ON k.id = t.keyindicator_id 
WHERE t.branch_id IN (241) AND t.period >= '2017-09' AND t.period < '2017-
10';
```