# postal code and location amounts in sql

Tags: sql

If it's been asked before then my search function is cursed.

```
select postkode, gemeente, count(postkode) as total 
from leveradressen 
where land=1 
group by postkode 
order by postkode asc
```

postkode is a zipcode
gemeente is the town name

i try to run this but i get

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'leveradressen.Gemeente' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

... no idea how to make it work. I know WHY he does it. but this is an assignment to see if i can keep this job and i'm utterly failing at it.

what's happening is he thinks that there's too many place names to pick from. but every place name matches every zipcode. there are never any deviations. 2000 will always be antwerpen, for example.

and no i can't fix it by adding a 'group by' because that's in there and i can't use aggregate functions because both postkode and plaatsnaam are both nvarchar.

i'm out of ideas.

Comment: It's been asked.  Up your search-fu by learning to search the error: [Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Comment: Question: you said 2000 is always Antwerp but Antwerp is always 2000? In other words, it's a 1-to-1 relationship?

Comment: @RobertKock yes. they're postal codes. x is y and y is x. one's just a number thingy and the other's a name thingy. but they're same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group by `gemeente` as well.
So:

```
select postkode, gemeente, count(postkode) as total 
from leveradressen 
where land=1 
group by postkode, gemeente
order by postkode asc
```

Not sure what you mean with  *i can't fix it by adding a 'group by' because that's in there*

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
select postkode, MIN(gemeente) AS gemeente, count(postkode) as total 
                 -- here goes agg function
from leveradressen 
where land=1 
group by postkode 
order by postkode asc
```

Comment: .... i tried this before and it didn't work. how the frick does it work now??? freaking space demons, that's why. thank you!