# The division of each row by the sum of the rows that has the same value of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to calculate the division of each row per the sum of all rows that have the same **Dateadded** and **fundid**, but it seems my query is wrong due the results is not what I was expecting.
My table schema looks like this, I avoided mine because it has many more columns:

```
+----+--------+------------+--------+
| id | fundid | Dateadded  | amount |
+====+========+============+========+
| 1  |  45    | 21-02-2018 |  5412  |
| 2  |  45    | 21-02-2018 |  5414  |
| 3  |  45    | 21-02-2018 |  1412  |
| 4  |  45    | 22-02-2018 |  5756  |
| 5  |  45    | 22-02-2018 |  4412  |
| 6  |  45    | 25-02-2018 |  2532  |
| 7  |  45    | 26-02-2018 |  7892  |
| 8  |  45    | 26-02-2018 |  8143  |
+----+-------+-------------+--------+
```

- Rows with id's: 1,2,3 should be calculated together because they have
  the same fundid and date.
- Rows with id's: 4,5 same thing.
- Rows with id's: 6 it is just one.
- Rows with id's: 7,8 same thing.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT fundid
     , Dateadded
     , ( amount / SUM(amount) ) AS AvgRow 
  FROM stock2 
 GROUP 
    BY fundid
     , Dateadded 
 ORDER 
    BY DateAdded ASC
```

Comment: What is your expected output as per your sample dataset ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*, t.amount / tt.total_amount
from stock2  t join
     (select fundid, dateadded, sum(amount) as total_amount
      from stock2 t
      group by fundid, dateadded
     ) tt
     using (fundid, dateadded);
```

Or is this?

```
select fundid, dateadded, sum(t.amount) / tt.total_amount
from stock2  t cross join
     (select sum(amount) as total_amount
      from stock2 t
     ) tt
 group by fundid, dateadded, tt.total_amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out a very well explained response to a similar issue related to usage of **Group by** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13999903/8165999)).

Similarly to the situation described there, for your query is ambiguous re: what "amount" should be used for each row. I.e. if you try:

```
    SELECT fundid, Dateadded, ( AVG(amount) / SUM(amount) ) AS AvgRow FROM stock2 GROUP BY fundid, Dateadded ORDER BY DateAdded ASC
```

it will work because **AVG(amount)** is non-ambiguous for each **(fundid, Dateadded)** pair that should be calculated together.

It seems you are looking for something like:

```
   SELECT st.fundid, st.Dateadded, ( amount / st2.total) ) AS AvgRow 
   FROM stock2 st 
   inner join 
      (select fundid, Dateadded, sum(amount) as total
       from stock2
       GROUP BY fundid, Dateadded) st2 
   on st.fundid = st2.fundid and st.Dateadded = st2.Dateadded
   order by st.Dateadded
```