# Sql Aggregate function with join

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 SELECT ORDERS.ORDERID,
        ORDERS.CUSTOMERID,
        ORDERS.EMPLOYEEID,
        ORDERDETAILS.PRODUCTID,
        ORDERDETAILS.UNITPRICE,
        ORDERDETAILS.QUANTITY,
        COUNT(ORDERS.ORDERID)
 FROM ORDERS
      LEFT JOIN ORDERDETAILS ON ORDERS.ORDERID=ORDERDETAILS.ORDERID
 GROUP BY ORDERDETAILS.ORDERID
```

> ERROR:Column 'ORDERS.OrderID' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Comment: use group by orders.orderid not group by orderdetails.orderid as it is not included in your select clause and i am completely unsure what you are trying to acheive with this query

Comment: This will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough (any) useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: SAME ERROR , IT IS INCLUDED IN select.

Comment: I suggest getting used to using aliases, and good use of whitespace as well; it'll make your SQL far easier to read for both yourself and others in the future.

Comment: More on topic; what it is you are trying to achieve here? Adding the full `GROUP BY` is going to give you a count of how many times the same product is listed in a single Order (which considering you have a quantity button, probably means you'll get the value 1). Is this meant to be a count of orders by customers? The key thing when asking a question is to *unsurprisingly*, ask a question; you haven't one just posted your SQL and an error. We can make your SQL work, but we don't know what your goal is. Ask a question, explain your goal.

Comment: Update your question  .. add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0):

For using aggregate function selected column will also need to include in group by clause

```
SELECT 
 ORDERS.ORDERID,ORDERS.CUSTOMERID,ORDERS.EMPLOYEEID,ORDERDETAILS.PRODUCTID,ORD ERDETAILS.UNITPRICE,ORDERDETAILS.QUANTITY,
 COUNT(ORDERS.ORDERID)
 FROM ORDERS LEFT JOIN ORDERDETAILS ON 
 ORDERS.ORDERID=ORDERDETAILS.ORDERID
 GROUP BY ORDERDETAILS.ORDERID,ORDERS.CUSTOMERID,ORDERS.EMPLOYEEID,ORDERDETAILS.PRODUCTID,ORD ERDETAILS.UNITPRICE,ORDERDETAILS.QUANTITY
```

Comment: This'll work, but based on the query the OP has this is probably going to return the value `1` for every row; which is unlikely to be what they want

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you intend this:

```
SELECT o.ORDERID, o.CUSTOMERID, o.EMPLOYEEID,
       COUNT(od.ORDERID) as NUM_PRODUCTS
FROM ORDERS o LEFT JOIN
     ORDERDETAILS od
     ON o.ORDERID = od.ORDERID
GROUP BY o.ORDERID;
```

This produces one row per `ORDERID` with a count of the number of products (or more specifically `orderdetails` rows) in each order.

Notes:

- All unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` should be `GROUP BY` keys.
- You don't want to include unaggregated columns from `ORDERDETAILS` in the `SELECT`, because then an `ORDER` might have multiple rows in the result set.
- You do want to use table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.