# Understanding a SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to modify a stored procedure on a Microsoft SQL server that is used to get data for a SSRS table.  It currently filters by a few parameters, one of them "Analyst" but I would like for the query to return the analyst as well to the report so if you leave the parameter empty it would you could still see what analyst was assigned the ticket

This is the code used to find the analyst info, how can I edit it to allow me to return the Analyst display name as well?

```
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT  
        Analyst.UserName AS AnalystASURITE, 
        Analyst.DisplayName AS DisplayName, 
        Analyst.UserDimKey,
        WIATUFact.WorkItemDimKey
    FROM 
        dbo.UserDim Analyst
        JOIN 
            dbo.WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw WIATUFact
            ON Analyst.UserDimKey = WIATUFact.WorkItemAssignedToUser_UserDimKey

        WHERE WIATUFact.DeletedDate IS NULL -- We only need the information for the last analyst assigned.
        GROUP BY WIATUFact.WorkItemDimKey, Analyst.UserName, Analyst.DisplayName, Analyst.UserDimKey, WIATUFact.CreatedDate
    ) AssignedAnalystInfo
        ON AssignedAnalystInfo.WorkItemDimKey = WI.WorkItemDimKey
```

I added

```
Analyst = AssignedAnalystInfo.DisplayName,
```

to the top of my procedure and it was correct syntax but got this error

```
Column 'AssignedAnalystInfo.DisplayName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I can add the whole procedure if that is needed but it's pretty long.

```
    USE [DWDataMart]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[RTS_Report_IncidentManagement_GetIncidentMetricData2018]    Script Date: 11/29/2018 2:30:26 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RTS_Report_IncidentManagement_GetIncidentMetricData2018]
    @StartDate  datetime,
    @EndDate    datetime,
    @LanguageCode nvarchar(max)= 'ENU',
    @Department nvarchar(max) = '',
    @Analyst nvarchar(max) = '',
    @AffectedUser nvarchar(max) = '',
    @DateFilter nvarchar(256) = 'CreatedOn',
    @SupportGroups nvarchar(max) = -1,
    @Priority nvarchar(max) = -1

AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    /* Adds a day to the End Date if it is set to midnight. 
    This is needed as the console picks midnight of the End Date which cuts off the last day. 
    Otherwise it simply leaves it as is.*/
    If (@EndDate = cast(@EndDate as date)) 
        SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)

    DECLARE @Error int
    DECLARE @ExecError int

    DECLARE @tableDept TABLE (value nvarchar(256))
    INSERT @tableDept (value)
    SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_CSVToTableString(@Department)

    DECLARE @tableAnalyst TABLE (value nvarchar(256))
    INSERT @tableAnalyst(value)
    SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_CSVToTableString(@Analyst)

    DECLARE @tableAffectedUser TABLE (value nvarchar(256))
    INSERT @tableAffectedUser(value)
    SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_CSVToTableString(@AffectedUser)

    DECLARE @tableSupportGroups TABLE (value nvarchar(256))
    INSERT @tableSupportGroups (value)
    SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_CSVToTableInt(@SupportGroups)

    DECLARE @tablePriority TABLE (value nvarchar(256))
    INSERT @tablePriority (value)
    SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_CSVToTableInt(@Priority)



    SELECT 

        --We need some datasets.  This SP will pull each incident based on the parameters.  How it is displayed
        --depends on the report running this SP.    

        IncidentTitle = I.Title,

        AffectedUser = AffectedUserInfo.DisplayName,          

        IncidentIR = I.Id, 

        AAnalyst = AssignedAnalystInfo.DisplayName,

        IRCreatedDate = I.CreatedDate,

        IRResolvedDate = I.ResolvedDate,

        TimeToAssignment = CASE
            WHEN
            (
                FirstAssignedDate.CreatedDate IS NOT NULL
                AND 
                I.Priority > 3
            )
            THEN
                DATEDIFF(MINUTE, I.CreatedDate, FirstAssignedDate.CreatedDate)
            ELSE NULL
            END,

        TimeWorked = CASE
            WHEN
            (
                (TotalBT.TimeWorked IS NOT NULL)
            )
            THEN
                TotalBT.TimeWorked
            ELSE NULL
            END,

        TimeToResolution = CASE
            WHEN
            (
                (I.Status = 'IncidentStatusEnum.Resolved' OR I.Status = 'IncidentStatusEnum.Closed')
                AND
                (I.CreatedDate IS NOT NULL)
                AND
                (I.ResolvedDate IS NOT NULL)
                AND
                (I.Priority > 3)
            )
            THEN
                DATEDIFF(MINUTE, I.CreatedDate, I.ResolvedDate) - dFact.PendingDuration
            ELSE NULL
            END, 

    -- Unseen stuff is selected and processed accordingly
        IncidentDimKey = I.IncidentDimKey


    FROM dbo.IncidentDim I


    -- JOINS to other needed tables 

    -- Join the incident dimension to the workitem dimension.
    INNER JOIN dbo.WorkItemDim WI
        ON WI.EntityDimKey = I.EntityDimKey



    --Join the AssignedTo fact table to the workitem table.  We can use this to get information on the assigned
    --analyst.
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
        SELECT  
            Analyst.UserName AS AnalystASURITE, 
            Analyst.DisplayName AS DisplayName, 
            Analyst.UserDimKey,
            WIATUFact.WorkItemDimKey
        FROM 
            dbo.UserDim Analyst
            JOIN 
                dbo.WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw WIATUFact
                ON Analyst.UserDimKey = WIATUFact.WorkItemAssignedToUser_UserDimKey

            WHERE WIATUFact.DeletedDate IS NULL -- We only need the information for the last analyst assigned.
            GROUP BY WIATUFact.WorkItemDimKey, Analyst.UserName, Analyst.DisplayName, Analyst.UserDimKey, WIATUFact.CreatedDate
        ) AssignedAnalystInfo
            ON AssignedAnalystInfo.WorkItemDimKey = WI.WorkItemDimKey

    --Join the Assigned To fact table so we can calculate the assignment times.  Only need the first assignment information.
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
        SELECT
            WorkItemDimKey, 
            MIN(CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate
        FROM 
            dbo.WorkItemAssignedToUserFactvw WIATUFact
        GROUP BY WorkItemDimKey
        ) FirstAssignedDate
            ON FirstAssignedDate.WorkItemDimKey = WI.WorkItemDimKey


    --Start Total TimeWorked joins.  We can pull time and sum per incident.
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
        SELECT
            SUM(BT.TimeInMinutes) AS TimeWorked, 
            WIBTFact.WorkItemDimKey
        FROM
            dbo.BillableTimeDim BT
            JOIN
                dbo.WorkItemHasBillableTimeFactvw WIBTFact
                ON BT.BillableTimeDimKey = WIBTFact.WorkItemHasBillableTime_BillableTimeDimKey  
            GROUP BY WIBTFact.WorkItemDimKey
    ) TotalBT
        ON TotalBT.WorkItemDimKey = WI.WorkItemDimKey

    --Join the AffectedUser fact table to the workitem table.  We need this so we have some information about 
    --the affeted user.
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
        SELECT 
            UserName,
            DisplayName,
            Department =
            CASE
                WHEN(Department = '' OR Department IS NULL)
                THEN 'Unknown'
                ELSE Department
            END,
            WIAUFact.WorkItemDimKey

        FROM UserDim AffectedUserInfo

        JOIN dbo.WorkItemAffectedUserFactvw WIAUFact ON AffectedUserInfo.UserDimKey = WIAUFact.WorkItemAffectedUser_UserDimKey
        AND
        WIAUFact.DeletedDate IS NULL

        GROUP BY WorkItemDimKey, CreatedDate, UserName, Department, DisplayName
    ) AS AffectedUserInfo
        ON AffectedUserInfo.WorkItemDimKey = WI.WorkItemDimKey

    --Next two JOIN needed so we can pull the name and enum values for the support groups.
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IncidentTierQueues AS SupportGroupEnum
        ON SupportGroupEnum.IncidentTierQueuesId = I.TierQueue_IncidentTierQueuesId

    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        dbo.DisplayStringDim SupportGroupDS
        ON SupportGroupEnum.EnumTypeId=SupportGroupDS.BaseManagedEntityId
        AND SupportGroupDS.LanguageCode = @LanguageCode

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                ActiveDuration = SUM(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN statusEnum.ID = 'IncidentStatusEnum.Active'
                            THEN dFact.TotalTimeMeasure
                            ELSE 0
                        END 
                        ),
                PendingDuration = SUM(
                        CASE 
                            WHEN statusEnum.ID = 'IncidentStatusEnum.Active.Pending'
                            THEN dFact.TotalTimeMeasure
                            ELSE 0
                        END 
                        ),
                dFact.IncidentDimKey
            FROM
            dbo.IncidentStatusDurationFactvw dFact

            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                dbo.IncidentStatus statusEnum
                ON statusEnum.IncidentStatusId = dFact.IncidentStatusId
            GROUP BY dfact.IncidentDimKey       
        ) dFact
            ON dFact.IncidentDimKey = I.IncidentDimKey


    WHERE
        (@StartDate <= @EndDate)
        AND
        I.CreatedDate >= @StartDate
        AND
        I.CreatedDate <= @EndDate
        AND
        (
            (@DateFilter = 'ClosedOn' AND ((I.ClosedDate >= @StartDate) AND (I.ClosedDate < @EndDate))) OR
            (@DateFilter = 'CreatedOn' AND ((I.CreatedDate >= @StartDate) AND (I.CreatedDate < @EndDate))) OR
            (@DateFilter = 'ResolvedOn' AND ((I.ResolvedDate >= @StartDate) AND (I.ResolvedDate < @EndDate))) 
        )
        AND
        ((-1 IN (Select value from @tableSupportGroups)) OR (CASE WHEN (SupportGroupEnum.IncidentTierQueuesId IS NULL) THEN '0' ELSE SupportGroupEnum.IncidentTierQueuesId END IN (SELECT value FROM @tableSupportGroups)))
        AND
        (('' IN (Select value from @tableDept)) OR (AffectedUserInfo.Department IN (Select value from @tableDept)))
        AND     
        (('' IN (Select value from @tableAnalyst)) OR (AssignedAnalystInfo.AnalystASURITE IN(Select value from @tableAnalyst)))
        AND
        (('' IN (Select value from @tableAffectedUser)) OR (AffectedUserInfo.UserName IN(Select value from @tableAffectedUser)))
        AND
        ((-1 IN (Select value from @tablePriority)) OR (I.Priority IN (Select value from @tablePriority)))

    GROUP BY
        I.Title,
        I.Id,
        I.CreatedDate,
        I.ResolvedDate,
        I.Priority,
        I.Status,
        I.IncidentDimKey,
        TimeWorked,
        AffectedUserInfo.DisplayName,
        FirstAssignedDate.CreatedDate,
        dFact.PendingDuration

SET @Error = @@ERROR

QuitError:
    Return @Error
END
```

Comment: I don't see a parameter for Analyst... can you show that, and where it's being used? The error is self-explanatory, meaning you need to add it to the group by list if you want that column returned

Comment: You need to include that column in the group by statement as well, otherwise it must not be part of the select

Comment: try using `outer apply` instead of `left join`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e

Comment: How would I include the column in the group statement? I wasn't able to figure out to do it without getting some kind of error. 

scsimon - The parameters are all at the beginning, I'll add the rest of the procedure as well.

Comment: Try to add it to the last group by statement

Comment: That worked! Thank you!