# Invalid t1.id in select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or group by clause

Tags: sql-server

I have two table t1 and t2,
Where t1 has the data like:

> Id.    Name
>     1.       Ab
>     2.       Dc
>     3.       Cd

t2 has the data as given:

> Id.    Revenue
>   1.      100
>   2.       0
>   3.       200

And my SQL query is:

```
select t1.id ,t1.name,sum(t2.rev)
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id= t2.id
where t1.id=100 and t2.Revenue <> 0
group by t1.id
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put to `GROUP BY` columns that you want to select:

```
select t1.id ,t1.name,sum(t2.rev)
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id= t2.id
where t1.id=100 and t2.Revenue <> 0
group by t1.id, t1.name, t2.rev
```

The error means that that you've got `SUM` of `t2.rev` field - one row, but SQL Server has also many rows with calculated column and it does not know what a row exactly should be chosen.

**UPDATE:**

If one of your some column has type such as `text`, `ntext` or `image`, then you should cast it to `NVARCHAR` type:

```
select t1.id ,t1.name,sum(t2.rev)
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id= t2.id
where t1.id=100 and t2.Revenue <> 0
group by t1.id, CAST( t1.name AS NVARCHAR(100)), CAST( t2.rev AS  NVARCHAR(100))
```

**UPDATE 1:**

`TEXT`, `NTEXT` and `IMAGE` are old type of variable and there types are deprecated. So these types be replaced or casted by the corresponding types `VARCHAR(MAX)`, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

If you have just one column of type of `TEXT`, then just `CAST` just this column:

```
select t1.id ,t1.name,sum(t2.rev)
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id= t2.id
where t1.id=100 and t2.Revenue <> 0
group by t1.id, CAST( t1.name AS NVARCHAR(100)), t2.rev
```

Comment: After applying this query i am getting (the text ,ntext and image data types can not be compared or sorted,except when using is null or like operator) error

Comment: Thanks @stepup it is working now but my column datatype was in decimal.

Comment: @mahadevdhyani feel free to ask any question. Of it helps to you, you can mark it as an answer to simplify future search of other people.

Comment: But i just want explaination that only name was in text apart from that all were in decimal then why was this error shown in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

If anything, the column causing the error would be `t1.name1` Since the name is completely dependent on the ID, you can artificially add it to the `group by` clause without harming the query's correctness:

```
select t1.id ,t1.name,sum(t2.rev)
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id= t2.id
where t1.id=100 and t2.Revenue <> 0
group by t1.id, t1.name
```

Comment: After applying this query i am getting (the text ,ntext and image data types can not be compared or sorted,except when using is null or like operator) error

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display any column and you used group by than you must group by one those column also

```
select t1.id ,t1.name,sum(t2.Revenue) from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id= t2.id where t1.id=1 and t2.Revenue <> 0 group by t1.id,t1.Name
```