# how to use group by in select statement in vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net-2010

I have table that contains data like this:

```
add_ser       add_date          customer_name
1               16/02/2018           asd
1               16/02/2018           asd
1               16/02/2018           asd
2               16/03/2018           qwe
2               16/03/2018           qwe
3                16/03/2018          asd
4                15/4/2018           zxc
4                15/4/2018           zxc
```

I want to run `SELECT` statement with `GROUP BY` `add_ser`, but this code returns with an error:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select add_ser,customer_name,add_date from add_items GROUP By add_ser"
```

Comment: please add what error you got.

Comment: Your query does not include the specified expression 'customer_name' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using group by on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e