# sql server how to distinct data from multiple column but not all column

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have a problem, I need to show unique data from some table, sql server based,  ihave the query but I have a error if not all column I select is not contain in the `GROUP BY`.

Table source:

```
+------+------+----------+-------+
| code | name | process  | time  |
+------+------+----------+-------+
| a    | qq   | write    | 10:10 |
| b    | qq   | read     | 11:10 |
| c    | qq   | read     | 12:11 |
| a    | qq   | write    | 09:40 |
| b    | yy   | write    | 08:50 |
| a    | yy   | read     | 11:10 |
| b    | yy   | write    | 09:40 |
+------+------+----------+-------+
```

Table I need:

```
+------+------+----------+-------+
| code | name | process  | time  |
+------+------+----------+-------+
| a    | qq   | write    | 10:10 |
| b    | qq   | read     | 11:10 |
| b    | yy   | write    | 09:40 |
| c    | qq   | read     | 12:11 |
| a    | yy   | read     | 11:10 |
+------+------+----------+-------+
```

Code I use:

```
select code, name, process, time 
from tablesource 
group by code, name, process;
```

But this query result in error:

> [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Column
>   'time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in
>   either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. (8120),

But if  column time I insert in `group by`, the result is just same as the table source. Please help me.

Comment: When you have two different timestamps, for a group of code, name, process, which timestamp do you need the query to return ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify query to add aggregate function for time.

```sql
select code, name, process, max(time) from tablesource 
group by code, name, process;
```