# How to write proper MySQL case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I’ve typed out the query below and I get a syntax error after the first when of the the CASE part. Please help correct.

```
SELECT state.name, country.name, AVG(state_weather_stats.humidity) AS average_monthly_humidity,
CASE AVG(state_weather_stats.temperature)
    WHEN >=0 AND < 15 THEN “COLD”
    WHEN >= 15 AND <30 THEN “WARM”
    ELSE “HOT”
END AS weather_type
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using inequalities, you can't use the `CASE <expr> WHEN ...` syntax. That syntax is only usable when you're doing equality comparisons.

So you can use the `CASE WHEN <expr> ...` syntax instead:

```
SELECT state.name, country.name, AVG(state_weather_stats.humidity) AS average_monthly_humidity,
CASE 
    WHEN average_monthly_humidity >= average_monthly_humidity THEN 'COLD'
    WHEN average_monthly_humidity >= 15 AND average_monthly_humidity <30 THEN ...something...
    ELSE 'HOT'
END AS weather_type
```

I don't know what you want where I put "...something..." but you do need a THEN clause before the ELSE.

Comment: I fixed that and now I have another error: ERROR 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains non aggregated  column state.name from the line GROUP BY state.name, country.name

Comment: That's a separate question, but I have a highly upvoted answer to explain that error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e/13999903#13999903