# MySQL Error #1055 When getting"leaderboard" stats

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT unitidentifier, unitdiscordid, count(unitdiscordid) 
FROM warnings 
GROUP BY unitdiscordid 
ORDER BY count(unitdiscordid) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

This is the query I'm running and I get the following error:

> #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'libertyr_cad.warnings.unitidentifier'
> which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;
> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I tried altering the query but still no luck, I know there is a fix by editing the `sql_mode` but I would prefer if possible to find a fix without doing that.

Comment: Run this command: desc warnings and post it here

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3c84acef9a7b0f9b401c59eaaf1d2a0c @YuriMelo

Comment: The improper solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by   The proper solution is to group by `unitidentifier, unitdiscordid` .

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e/13999903#13999903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing a `GROUP BY`, you are doing an aggregation and your individual, record-level fields are not necessarily accessible. You will need to add the fields you use into the `GROUP BY` in order to ensure that they are taken into account for the aggregation:

```
SELECT unitidentifier, unitdiscordid, count(unitdiscordid) 
FROM warnings 
GROUP BY unitidentifier, unitdiscordid 
ORDER BY count(unitdiscordid) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```