# How to filter out duplicates from a union query?

Tags: mysql

I have two similar SELECT queries that retrieve data from the same table "my_table".

```
-- 1st select
SELECT 
    my_table.id,
    a,
    b
FROM my_table
JOIN table2 ON u = v
JOIN table3 ON x = y

UNION ALL

-- 2st select
SELECT 
    my_table.id,
    a,
    b
FROM my_table
JOIN table2 ON r = s
JOIN table3 ON t = u
```

Duplicates are to be filtered out under the following conditions:
If the second select returns an id that is already present in the 1st select, it should be discarded.

Is there an easy solution without using a common table expression?

Note: The SQL does not have to be a UNION and can also be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
-- 1st select
SELECT 
    my_table.id,
    a,
    b
FROM my_table
JOIN table2 ON u = v
JOIN table3 ON x = y
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT 
        my_table.id,
    FROM my_table
    JOIN table2 ON r = s
    JOIN table3 ON t = u
)

UNION ALL

-- 2st select
SELECT 
    my_table.id,
    a,
    b
FROM my_table
JOIN table2 ON r = s
JOIN table3 ON t = u
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` filters out duplicate rows by default. `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicates.

But the duplicates are based on *all* columns being identical, not just the `id` column. If a given `id` value occurs in both queries, but any of the other two columns are different, then it counts as a distinct row.

If you want to reduce the result to a single row per `id`, the use a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT id, ...aggregate expressions... 
FROM (
  SELECT my_table.id, a, b ...
  UNION
  SELECT my_table.id, a, b ...
) AS t
GROUP BY id;
```

When you `GROUP BY id`, then any other expressions of the outer select-list must be in aggregate functions like MAX() or SUM(), etc.

---

The reason it is important to use an aggregate function is that when there are multiple rows with the same `id` value which you want to reduce to one row, what value should be displayed for `a` and `b`?

Example:

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 12 | 24 |
| 4 | 18 | 28 |

If you group by `id`, you would get one row for `id=4`, but what value for the other two columns?

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | ? | ? |

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html for more details on this. Or my answer to [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e/13999903#13999903)

You must use an aggregate function, which includes [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) to append all the values from that column in a comma-separated list. Or you can use [ANY_VALUE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) which picks one of the values from that column arbitrarily.

Comment: How do I SELECT id, a, b in the outer select without using aggregate functions? Because I do not need to use any of these functions.

Comment: "but what value for the other two columns?" If the 1st and 2nd selects return a row with the same id, the row of the 2nd select should be discarded. Hence, the a, b values of the 1st select are shown.