# How can I remove Duplicates row(Distinct doesn't work)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been strugling today Because am trying to remove all the duplicates but it doesn't work

`SELECT DISTINCT pays, nom, count(titre) FROM film JOIN personne ON film.idRealisateur = personne.id GROUP BY nom ORDER BY count(titre) DESC LIMIT 10`

OUTPUT

[image]

Even When I used DISTINCT I got Duplicates in the column pays

Comment: Distinctness is based on the columns you have selected. The rows returned are still distinct.

Comment: All youir data looks distinct to me. Perhaps read the documentation on distinct to understand what it does?

Answer (score 2):

A more clear answer than the comments above: `DISTINCT` applies to *all* the columns, not just the first column. In your example, you have three rows with a `pays` value of "France", but because they have different values of `nom`, the rows count as distinct rows.

If you want to reduce the result to one row per value of a specific column, then you should use GROUP BY, not DISTINCT.

```
SELECT pays, count(titre) 
FROM film JOIN personne ON film.idRealisateur = personne.id 
GROUP BY pays 
ORDER BY count(titre) DESC LIMIT 10
```

I took out `nom` from this example because if you reduce to one row for the three rows with `pays` = "France", then what do you want returned as the value of `nom`? There are three different values to choose from, and MySQL shouldn't make a guess at which one you want. For more explanation on this idea, see my answer to [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e/13999903#13999903)

Answer (score 0):

As per your table given, it seems like there is a duplicate nom available for the same country. for e.g, As per the first row Pays **UK** has noms **Charlie Chaplin** which is the **19th time** given in the table as per count(titre).

If you want to remove duplicate rows for a particular column like Pays and noms, we should use Group By with Delete statement.

First of all, perform the query given below.

```
DELETE FROM films
    WHERE filmID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT MAX(filmID) AS MaxRecordID
        FROM films
        GROUP BY pays,nom
    );
```

Then perform Group By statement with Select

```
select pays,nom ,count(*) as totalcount from films Group by pays,nom;
```

Also, attached screen shot with the result to clarify the questions.

[Result with removed duplicate rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dttYy.png)