# Msg 8120 - Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select sum(orderinfo.orderamount) as total, userinfo.username
from orderinfo
left join userinfo on orderinfo.userid = userinfo.userid
group by orderinfo.userid
order by total desc
```

Table orderinfo:

```
userid
orderamount
```

Table userinfo:

```
userid
username
```

I will need to search for top 10 most buy users with their names.

But I got this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Column 'userinfo.username' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I am using SSMS. I must be doing something wrong...please help

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Column+is+invalid+in+the+select+list+because+it+is+not+contained+in+either+an+aggregate+function+or+the+GROUP+BY+clause:

"As we know that “group by” return single row, so we need to apply an aggregate function to columns not used in group by clause to avoid this error."

Comment: Add username to the group by.   In an aggregation query, a column is either an aggregation or included in the group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot aggregate by the `userid` and also select the `username`.  The quickest fix here would be to aggregate by *both* the `userid` and `username`:

```sql
SELECT SUM(oi.orderamount) AS total, ui.username
FROM orderinfo oi
LEFT JOIN userinfo ui ON oi.userid = ui.userid
GROUP BY ui.userid, ui.username
ORDER BY total DESC;
```