# Unable to select column from other table while with COUNT and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in a SQL Server database - `IT_Order` and `Product`. I want to group by the `product_id` from `IT_Order` but also select the product name from `Product`. But I get an error for this query. Please help...

The tables:

[image]

The query:

```
SELECT  
    Product.product_name, IT_Order.product_id, 
    COUNT(IT_Order.it_order_id) AS Product_volume 
FROM 
    IT_Order, Product
WHERE 
    IT_Order.product_id = Product.product_id
GROUP BY 
    IT_Order.product_id;
```

I get this error:

> Column 'Product.product_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Did you read the words in the error message? They tell you **exactly** what is wrong, and **exactly** how to fix it. Add `Product.product_name` to the `GROUP BY` clause. All columns in the `SELECT` that are not aggregated (SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, COUNT) must be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: May I know if there is no way to do it?

Comment: I just told you that, and so did the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e). There are more than 1000 additional results for a search here for the words in the error message which you could have found if you had bothered to search.

Comment: Sorry that I am new to SQL and thank you for your advice so much. Now I get it.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Maybe you want a windowed aggregate, for example `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id)` which means you get all rows, but the count is calculated over a section of rows at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear, you can use column without  aggregation, in a GROUP BY, but as every product has only one name(i guess) you can make

```
SELECT  Product.product_name, IT_Order.product_id, COUNT(IT_Order.it_order_id) as 
Product_volume 
FROM IT_Order JOIN Product
ON IT_Order.product_id = Product.product_id
GROUP BY IT_Order.product_id,Product.product_name;
```

also please use in future JOIN for your table, as they are around for 30 years now.