# Getting NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER deprecation warning while running seeds in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently upgraded the MySQL version of my rails application from 5.6 and 5.7 and I am facing this issue while seeding my database.

When I run the seeding, it fails/aborts with the following message.

```
MysqlWarning: Changing sql mode 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' is deprecated. It will be removed in a future release.
```

I have NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER mode enabled in my database but it is still failing.

[image]

Can someone please tell me what can I do to fix this issue? Should I  simply remove this mode from my database or is there another way to fix this?

Note: I removed the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode from the database earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't remove NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER. This is a good feature, and in MySQL 8.0 it's enforced behavior.

The reason it is important is for security. MySQL historically allowed you to create a new user implicitly, by granting that user privileges. The problem was that people did the grant without assigning a password:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to 'newuser'@'%';
```

When a GRANT automatically creates a user, this would silently create the new user *with no password.* That's a big security no-no.

By requiring new users to be created with CREATE USER before they can be granted privileges, it ensures that users will be created deliberately with a password (or other authentication like a TLS certificate).

To fix this, you should change your Rails seed code to execute CREATE USER before granting privileges. Or else make it a manual step to create the MySQL user before running your Rails seed code.

P.S.: You shouldn't disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY either. It's important to prevent invalid queries. See my explanation here: [Reason for Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e/13999903#13999903)