# Why is this SQL statement wrong?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

At about 02:16 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=br5J8MsduJo&list=PLYp4IGUhNFmw8USiYMJvCUjZe79fvyYge&index=10) the professor said that this SQL statement has some problem and cannot be implemented:

```sql
SELECT S.name, AVG(S.gpa)
FROM Students S
GROUP BY S.dept
```

I do not understand why and I created a table and it works.

Why do they say it is wrong and what are any errors in my examples?

```sql
CREATE TABLE Students(
    name CHAR(20),
    gpa FLOAT,
    department CHAR(20)
);

Insert INTO Students VALUES
    ('001', 4.0, 'CS'),
    ('002', 3.5, 'MATH'),
    ('003', 3.7, 'STAT'),
    ('004', 4.1, 'CS');
```

Expected output from my MySQL 5.5:
[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7idX.png)

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the _same columns_ as you `SELECT` - _except_ those who are arguments to aggregate functions.

Comment: There is no dept column in students and you should be grouping by the non aggregated columns in the select - mysql will let you get away with this when only_full_group_by is not set.

Comment: It works in older mysql versions. in newer mysql versions and other dbms it doesn't work, because you select values, that are not part of the group by clause

Comment: In your example you group by `S.dept`, so your `001` and `004` records are grouped together. What is `S.name` supposed to return now? It can be both `001` and `004`.

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to run through a fiddle where you can test against versions https://dbfiddle.uk/Z8DUbmM5

Comment: You might like my explanation of the single-value rule here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/reason-for-column-is-invalid-in-the-select-list-because-it-is-not-contained-in-e/13999903#13999903

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) . Especially don't ask us to watch video.  [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Please avoid social & meta content in posts.

Answer (score 0):

This 'functionality' in MySQL is controlled by the sql_mode only [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) which in older MySQL versions is disabled by default.

In simple word , the data returned from the columns in the select statement which are nor part of an aggregate function nor part of the group by clause are arbitrary (you can't control which values are returned).

For example based on your data example the following query for the `CS` department would return `001` , but there is `004` name as well

```
SELECT S.name, S.department
FROM Students S
GROUP BY S.department;
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/kxFip5cK)

See [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) for further info.