# SQL Aggregation of text on joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate

Pardon the lack of correct terminology, I'm a professional software engineer usually dealing with Direct3D frameworks. I'm self taught on databases.

I have a `_People` table and an `_Ethnicities` table.  Since people may have more than one cultural group I have a link table `_linkPersonEthnicity`.  Sample data is shown below:

[image: SampleData]

What I want is output in the following form:
[image]

To illustrate the problem I present the following (runnable) query:

```
select lPE.Person, Sum(E.ID) as SumOfIDs,
   Ethnicity = stuff(
      (select ', ' + Max(E.Name) as [text()]
        from _linkPersonEthnicity xPE
        where xPE.Person = lPE.Person
        for xml path('')
      ),
    1, 2, '')
from _Ethnicities E 
join _linkPersonEthnicity lPE on lPE.Ethnicity = E.ID
group by lPE.Person
```

It returns the Person's ID, a sum of the IDs found for the person's ethnicity, and concatenates the maximum `Name` with commas.  The data is grouped correctly, and the SumOfIDs works, proving the correct data is used.

Naturally I would like to take away the `Max` aggregate function, but cannot since it is not in the `group by` list.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks in advance,

AM

---

(Many thanks to other answers on StackOverflow for getting me this far!  Particiularly @Jonathan Leffler for his [explanation of the partitioning proceess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611897/group-by-aggregate-function-confusion-in-sql) and @Marc_s for [illustrating a text concatenation technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string).)

I've also tried `coalesce` from an [answer to concatenating strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) by @Chris Shaffer

```
declare @Names VARCHAR(8000)
select @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + E.Name 
  from _Ethnicities E join _linkPersonEthnicity lPE on lPE.Ethnicity = E.ID
 where lPE.Person = 1001;
select @Names
```

Same problem.  If I remove the `where` and add `group by` the text field `Name` cannot be accessed.

Comment: You don't need an aggregate inside the subquery. Did you try and remove it? Also please see [this article](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) and [this follow-up](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation-2).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Off topic question :  Where can i find the list of all articles that you have written. If possible share me a link. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thank you sir. Will search in these sites. I found this http://sqlperformance.com/author/abertrand.

Comment: @AndrewMalcolm, it looks like you accidentally created two accounts.  If you sign in with your account used to ask this question, you can edit this post without having to push it into the review queue.  http://stackoverflow.com/users/4946944/andrew-malcolm  and.... http://stackoverflow.com/users/4604363/andrew

Comment: @DanielNugent - first time I've ever done the 'login with Google' thing.  Ironic as I've always been skeptical of linked IDs, but my thinking was if it will work anywhere it would work on a big tech site!  Obviously something glitched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need for the `join` to be in the subquery rather than the outer query

```
select lPE.Person, Sum(lpe.ethnicity) as SumOfIDs,
       Ethnicity = stuff((select ', ' + E.Name as [text()]
                          from _linkPersonEthnicity lPE2 join
                               _Ethnicities e
                               on lpe2.Ethnicity = e.id
                          where lpe2.Person = lPE.Person
                          for xml path('')
                         ), 1, 2, '')
from _linkPersonEthnicity lPE 
group by lPE.Person;
```

By the way, do you really want the sum of the ids or a count?

Comment: Not sure why or what the typo is but I get `The multi-part identifier "e.ID" could not be bound.`  Also I why did the comments for this answer get removed?  I've typed this once before, and @GordonLinoff did reply.  (Sadly I couldn't fix it with the previous reply.)

Comment: @AndrewMalcolm . . .  Your original query has `lPE.Ethnicity = E.ID` for the `join` condition.  This has the same condition in the subquery.  It should work if the joins in the original query were formulated correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the SumOfIDs expression which contained the `E.ID`.  (I didn't look at since I'm going to throw it away anyway.)  _Apologies_ for the hiccup and many thanks for the solution! . . . (As an append I did try this approach very early on but obviously stuffed up.  Ah well.)

Comment: BTW, SumOfIDs was put in there just to test I was getting the correct data back.