# CASE and GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql, case

I have been writing a query that allows me to select and count rows for specific product id's and shipment types. 
Within this data, what I am now trying to achieve is count which rows have a specific field populated (second member name) and which have not. Then return this as a separate column in my query results.

Here's the query which I have written:

```
select count(job.JobID) as itemsCount, Lookup_Pack.PackDescription, Lookup_Pack.PackCode, Lookup_Pack.ID, job.shipping,

CASE 
WHEN Job.secondMemForename <> '' THEN count(job.JobID)
ELSE 0
END AS [Extra card count]
from job 
inner join Lookup_Pack on Lookup_Pack.ID = job.packTypeID
where Lookup_Pack.PackType = 'REN'
AND job.createDate >= '2015-06-01' and Job.createDate <= '2015-06-30'
GROUP BY Lookup_Pack.PackDescription, Lookup_Pack.PackCode, Lookup_Pack.ID, Job.shipping
```

If I run this query, I get an error returned as I am not grouping by Job.secondMemForename:

> [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Column 'job.secondMemForename' is invalid in the
>   select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

although Job.secondMemForename does not form part of the query results. 
I have subsequently added this field to the GROUP BY statement, the problem with this is that the data returned for all rows where the CASE applies is un-grouped as the Job.secondMemForename is different for all of them.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Thanks.
Steeve.

Comment: May be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611897/group-by-aggregate-function-confusion-in-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Count()` to `Sum()` and add it before `CASE`

```
SUM (CASE WHEN Job.secondMemForename <> '' THEN 1 END)  AS [Extra card count]
```