# SELECT from subquery without having to specify all columns in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Idea is to query an `article` table where an article has a given `tag`, and then to `STRING_AGG` all (even unrelated) tags that belong to that article row.

Example tables and query:

```
CREATE TABLE article (id SERIAL, body TEXT);
CREATE TABLE article_tag (article INT, tag INT);
CREATE TABLE tag (id SERIAL, title TEXT);

SELECT DISTICT ON (id)
    q.id, q.body, STRING_AGG(q.tag_title, '|') tags
FROM (
    SELECT a.*, tag.title tag_title
    FROM article a
        LEFT JOIN article_tag x ON a.id = tag.article
        LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.id = x.tag
    WHERE tag.title = 'someTag'
) q
GROUP BY q.id
```

Running the above, postgres require that the `q.body` must be included in `GROUP BY`:

```
ERROR:  column "q.body" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

As I understand it, it's because subquery `q` doesn't include any PRIMARY key.

I naively thought that the `DISTINCT ON` would supplement that, but it doesn't seem so.

Is there a way to mark a column in a subquery as PRIMARY so that we don't have to list all columns in `GROUP BY` clause?

If we *do* have to list all columns in `GROUP BY` clause, does that incur significant perf cost?

**EDIT:** to elaborate, since [PostgreSQL 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release-9-1.html#AEN110817) you *don't have to* supply non-primary (i.e. *functionally dependent*) keys when using `GROUP BY`, e.g. following query works fine:

```
SELECT a.id, a.body, STRING_AGG(tag.title, '|') tags
FROM article a
    LEFT JOIN article_tag x ON a.id = tag.article
    LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.id = x.tag
GROUP BY a.id
```

I was wondering if I can leverage the same behavior, **but** with a subquery (by somehow indicating that `q.id` is a PRIMARY key).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GROUP BY / aggregate function confusion in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611897/group-by-aggregate-function-confusion-in-sql)

Comment: You *do* have to group on all the non-aggregate columns, due to using an aggregate function.

Comment: edited to elaborate on what I mean by not having to specify non-primary keys in GROUP BY (thus why it's not a duplicate of the above question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sadly doesn't work when you wrap your primary key in subquery and I don't know of any way to "mark it" as you suggested.

You can try this workaround using `window function` and `distinct`:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (id serial primary key, name text, value text);
CREATE TABLE test2 (id serial primary key, test1_id int, value text);

INSERT INTO test1(name, value)
           values('name1', 'test01'), ('name2', 'test02'), ('name3', 'test03');

INSERT INTO test2(test1_id, value)
           values(1, 'test1'), (1, 'test2'), (3, 'test3');

SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, name, string_agg(value2, '|') over (partition by id)
  FROM (SELECT test1.*, test2.value AS value2
          FROM test1
          LEFT JOIN test2 ON test2.test1_id = test1.id) AS sub;

id  name    string_agg
1   name1   test1|test2
2   name2   null
3   name3   test3
```

[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fa7067976f391c411cd148d20fbee062)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in outer `SELECT` - you should either aggregate columns either 
group by them. Postgres wants you to specify what to do with `q.body` - group by it or calculate aggregate. Looks little bit awkward but should work.

```
SELECT DISTICT ON (id)
    q.id, q.body, STRING_AGG(q.tag_title, '|') tags
FROM (
    SELECT a.*, tag.title tag_title
    FROM article a
        LEFT JOIN article_tag x ON a.id = tag.article
        LEFT JOIN tag ON tag.id = x.tag
    WHERE tag.title = 'someTag'
) q
GROUP BY q.id, q.body
--             ^^^^^^
```

Another way is to make a query to get `id` and aggregated `tags` then join `body` to it. If you wish I can make an example.

Comment: No need, I understand that. My question was whether I can work around it the same way as I could if I selected directly from `article` table, and not from a subquery.