# Column 'Book.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function

Tags: sql-server

I'm sending the next request in my data base:

```
Select Book.Name as 'Book', Count([dbo].[Order].ShopperId) as 'Amount orders'
from Book, [dbo].[Order]
where Book.BookId = [dbo].[Order].BookId and [dbo].[Order].Amount = 5;
```

And getting the next error:

> Column 'Book.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

How do I change my request to make it work?

Comment: Are you sure you are working in mysql? You have this tagged as mysql and sql server. The error message is a sql server message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GROUP BY / aggregate function confusion in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611897/group-by-aggregate-function-confusion-in-sql)

Comment: Regardless of the DBMS you are actually using you should consider using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: I am not sure how much more clear the error message can possibly be. You can't have a scalar value from a column in a query when there are aggregates without that column being used in an aggregate OR in the group by.

Comment: Count is a aggregation fuction, so write at the end the group by Book.Name and look if the result is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is SQL Server, try this

```
Select Book.Name as 'Book', 
Count([dbo].[Order].ShopperId) as 'Amount orders' 
from Book, [dbo].[Order] 
where Book.BookId = [dbo].[Order].BookId and [dbo].[Order].Amount = 5
GROUP BY Book.Name;
```

Or better:

```
Select B.Name as 'Book', 
Count(o.ShopperId) as 'Amount orders' 
from [dbo].Book b JOIN [dbo].[Order] o ON b.BookId = o.BookId
where o.Amount = 5
GROUP BY Book.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd format it like this:

```
SELECT [Book] = b.Name
    , [Amount orders] = Count(o.ShopperId) 
FROM Book as b 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] as o
    ON b.BookId = o.BookId 
WHERE o.Amount = 5
GROUP BY b.Name;
```