# Join SQL select statements using Union

Tags: sql, sql-server, union-all

I am trying to join three select queries using Union All but the error is displayed. It is working fine when I join the first two select statements. As I added the third statement I am not able to execute it.

**SQL Query**

```
WITH CTE_BOOKINGS (TotalRecurrance,TotalBookingsWithoutRecurrance,TotalBookingsWithRecurrance,RoomID) AS
(
SELECT 0,count(BK.pkBookingID) as TotalBookingsWithoutRecurrance,0, RM.roomID as RoomID
FROM dbo.tblBooking BK WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingItem BI WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BI.fkBookingID
INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingDateTime BDT WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BDT.fkBookingID
INNER JOIN Enterprise.tblRooms RM WITH (NOLOCK) ON BI.fkItemID=RM.roomID AND RM.fkResourceId=1
WHERE
BK.deleteBooking=0
AND BDT.UTC_bookingEnd > GETUTCDATE()
AND BI.primaryRoom=1
AND BI.Active=1
AND NOT EXISTS (select * from tblBookingRecurrance where fkBookingID=BK.pkBookingID AND ACTIVE=1)
AND RM.roomID=16867
group by RM.roomID

UNION ALL
 
SELECT count(distinct BR.fkRecurranceID) as TotalRecurrance,0,0, RM.roomID as RoomID
FROM dbo.tblBooking BK WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingItem BI WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BI.fkBookingID
INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingDateTime BDT WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BDT.fkBookingID
INNER JOIN Enterprise.tblRooms RM WITH (NOLOCK) ON BI.fkItemID=RM.roomID AND RM.fkResourceId=1
INNER JOIN tblBookingRecurrance BR WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BR.fkBookingID
WHERE
BK.deleteBooking=0
AND BDT.UTC_bookingEnd > GETUTCDATE()
AND BI.primaryRoom=1
AND BI.Active=1
AND RM.roomID=16867
AND BR.active=1
group by RM.roomID

UNION ALL

SELECT 0,0,count(BK.pkBookingID) as TotalBookingsWithRecurrance, RM.roomID as RoomID
FROM dbo.tblBooking BK WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingItem BI WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BI.fkBookingID
INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingDateTime BDT WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BDT.fkBookingID
INNER JOIN Enterprise.tblRooms RM WITH (NOLOCK) ON BI.fkItemID=RM.roomID AND RM.fkResourceId=1
WHERE
BK.deleteBooking=0
AND BDT.UTC_bookingEnd > GETUTCDATE()
AND BI.primaryRoom=1
AND BI.Active=1
AND RM.roomID=16867
group by RM.roomID
)

SELECT  SUM(TotalRecurrance + TotalBookingsWithoutRecurrance) as TotalBookings, TotalBookingsWithRecurrance, RoomID FROM CTE_BOOKINGS Group BY RoomID order by 1 desc
```

Below error is displayed when I run the query:

**Error**

```
Column 'CTE_BOOKINGS.TotalBookingsWithRecurrance' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `UNION`, the column names from the first `SELECT` is returned for the entire resultset. So, even though you specify "TotalBookingsWithoutRecurrance", "TotalRecurrance", and "TotalBookingsWithRecurrance", your resultset (given your current example) column header will be "TotalRecurrance".

I believe your problem lies in your final SELECT:

```
SELECT  SUM(TotalRecurrance + TotalBookingsWithoutRecurrance) as TotalBookings, TotalBookingsWithRecurrance, RoomID FROM CTE_BOOKINGS Group BY RoomID order by 1 desc
```

**TotalBookingsWithRecurrance** is not being grouped on nor are you performing some sort of an aggregate--hence the error.

To keep it as is you'd need to do:

```
SELECT SUM(TotalRecurrance + TotalBookingsWithoutRecurrance) as TotalBookings, TotalBookingsWithRecurrance, RoomID 
FROM CTE_BOOKINGS 
GROUP BY RoomID, TotalBookingsWithRecurrance
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

However, this will add an additional grouping level that I suspect you don't want.

Also, your columns do not appear to be aligned between your UNIONed statements, which is a must--at the very least a best practice (for me anyway).

I cannot test this, but try doing something like the following:

```
WITH CTE_BOOKINGS ( RoomID, RecurranceType, Recurrance, UnknownCol1, UnknownCol2  ) 
AS (    
    SELECT 
        RM.roomID AS RoomID,
        'TotalBookingsWithoutRecurrance' AS RecurranceType,
        COUNT ( BK.pkBookingID ) AS Recurrance,
        0 AS UnknownCol1,
        0 AS UnknownCol2
    FROM dbo.tblBooking BK WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingItem BI WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BI.fkBookingID
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingDateTime BDT WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BDT.fkBookingID
    INNER JOIN Enterprise.tblRooms RM WITH (NOLOCK) ON BI.fkItemID=RM.roomID AND RM.fkResourceId=1
    WHERE BK.deleteBooking=0
        AND BDT.UTC_bookingEnd > GETUTCDATE()
        AND BI.primaryRoom=1
        AND BI.Active=1
        AND NOT EXISTS (select * from tblBookingRecurrance where fkBookingID=BK.pkBookingID AND ACTIVE=1)
        AND RM.roomID=16867
    GROUP BY RM.roomID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        RM.roomID AS RoomID,
        'TotalRecurrance' AS RecurranceType,
        COUNT ( DISTINCT BR.fkRecurranceID ) AS Recurrance,
        0 AS UnknownCol1,
        0 AS UnknownCol2 
    FROM dbo.tblBooking BK WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingItem BI WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BI.fkBookingID
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingDateTime BDT WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BDT.fkBookingID
    INNER JOIN Enterprise.tblRooms RM WITH (NOLOCK) ON BI.fkItemID=RM.roomID AND RM.fkResourceId=1
    INNER JOIN tblBookingRecurrance BR WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BR.fkBookingID
    WHERE BK.deleteBooking=0
        AND BDT.UTC_bookingEnd > GETUTCDATE()
        AND BI.primaryRoom=1
        AND BI.Active=1
        AND RM.roomID=16867
        AND BR.active=1
    GROUP BY RM.roomID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        RM.roomID AS RoomID,
        'TotalBookingsWithRecurrance' AS RecurranceType,
        COUNT ( BK.pkBookingID ) AS Recurrance, 
        0 AS UnknownCol1,
        0 AS UnknownCol2
    FROM dbo.tblBooking BK WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingItem BI WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BI.fkBookingID
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblBookingDateTime BDT WITH (NOLOCK) ON BK.pkBookingID=BDT.fkBookingID
    INNER JOIN Enterprise.tblRooms RM WITH (NOLOCK) ON BI.fkItemID=RM.roomID AND RM.fkResourceId=1
    WHERE BK.deleteBooking=0
        AND BDT.UTC_bookingEnd > GETUTCDATE()
        AND BI.primaryRoom=1
        AND BI.Active=1
        AND RM.roomID=18841
    GROUP BY RM.roomID
)
SELECT
    SUM ( 
        CASE WHEN RecurranceType IN ( 'TotalRecurrance', 'TotalBookingsWithoutRecurrance' ) THEN Recurrance ELSE 0 END 
    ) AS TotalBookings, 
    SUM ( 
        CASE WHEN RecurranceType = 'TotalBookingsWithRecurrance' THEN Recurrance ELSE 0 END 
    ) AS TotalBookingsWithRecurrance, 
    RoomID 
FROM CTE_BOOKINGS
GROUP BY RoomID
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: Tried but an error displayed ->
Column 'CTE_BOOKINGS.RecurranceType' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Column 'CTE_BOOKINGS.Recurrance' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Check out the updated example above. I wish I could test this before posting, but I cannot, so it will be a bit of trial and error. Not the addition of SUM for TotalBookingsWithRecurrance.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting has nothing to do with the `UNION`. There's an error with the 3rd query. You need to fix that up before you can join it to the other 2.

If you're grouping by a single field, that field will be the only one selectable without an aggregate function. Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611897/group-by-aggregate-function-confusion-in-sql) explaining that in greater depth.

Looking at your query, you're filtering for a specific roomId, not sure what your exact goal is, but in that case, you shouldn't need a group by roomId.